# help with inline images/mail with cron - php?

Tags: php, cron, mailing

I've got mailings that need to be sended using cron. When I load the script manualy all works fine. With cron i get broken images.

to change the src of my img i used:

```
$body    = eregi_replace("managersrc_logo","images/managers/acertainlogo.jpg",$body);
```

Because i thaught that it is importent to use absolute paths i also tried:

```
$body    = eregi_replace("managersrc_logo","http://www.site.com/images/managers/acertainlogo.jpg",$body);
```

In that case i even do not see the images when i run the cronscript manualy. Nor the automated cron will display me the images.

When i check the source of the mail that is received i always see "cid:encryptedstuff" even if i use absolute paths? Why is that? I just want my absolute paths being printed in the src attribute of the img tag. Who changes my absolute path to cid: ? is it php, phpmailer or outlook itself?

Any help someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an older version of phpmailer. I updated to the new version and the images are displayed perfectly now!!

Answer (score 0):

can you post a sample html before and after being replaced (but before being sent)? maybe it has additional characters that break the url, ie src="/managersrc_logo". Also, maybe your mailing program has an option to integrate the images inside the message and can't find them?

Comment: <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="200" style="text-align: right"><img src="managersrc_logo" alt="" name="managerlogo" width="managerbreedte" height="managerhoogte" align="right" id="managerlogo2" /></td>
</tr>